# Copy installed packages into scratch orgs along with their settings

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

Can installed packages be copied (not installed) into scratch orgs? The same way they get copied to sandboxes.

We have quite a few managed packages installed in our dev hub. I do appreciate we can install them to a scratch org after it gets created, but can we get them copied with their configurations as well?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. You must install the managed packages, either through scripting or manually, into each scratch org.

Configuration is stored differently for each managed package - some might use Custom Settings, others Custom Metadata, others sObjects. You'd have to design a route to capture and load the configuration for each managed package's specific strategy.

*Disclaimer: I am part of the team building this free and open source product*: [CumulusCI](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-applications-with-cumulusci) is designed for this kind of automation, and in particular comes with managed package dependency management for scratch orgs out of the box.

Comment: It's pretty shameful Salesforce didn't build-in package dependency installation based on `sfdx-project.json` content... we didn't use CumulusCI to resolve this but wrote scripting that uses the `sfdx-project.json` with some specially named "packageAliases" that hold the dependency package installation keys/passwords (these are nicely retained when sfdx rewrites the JSON file on package version creation which is why we took this approach). You're spot on with the answer though.

Comment: At some point Salesforce should provide the "scratch org snapshot" concept, of course, which should mean a scratch org can be created from a "template" that already includes the dependency packages... the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_org.htm) includes reference to pilot commands for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you also manage to export private custom settings data for managed packages?

Comment: As in Protected Custom Settings? No, that's not possible. You can export and load non-protected Custom Settings.